# Adding the HTML sign-in button to your page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a HTML sign-in button to my website using Google+ but when I click on the button nothing happens. 
I've followed the instructions given by Google on [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button). 
here's my code:

```
</head>
<body>

<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="900023009741-g4eodlf59og2i6rkllcdcmlqu4c3got8.apps.googleusercontent.com" // my client ID details which I have created on google's developer console
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
<script>
function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {

    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  } else {
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
</script>
</span>
</body>
```

The button appears when previewed in a browser but doesn't appear to work. Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: it error means u r client id mistake.once again check u r client id

Comment: Actually i am giving this one http://localhost:8080 in "JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS" because i do not have a domain.

Comment: u have rewrite htaccess file

Comment: htaccess file? which file is this?